# NodeJs and React with Firebase auth: how to secure nodejs api endpoints?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have an app with a NodeJS backend (with Express) and a React frontend.
The user auth is directly handled by the frontend with the help of Firebase Authentication.
Now, I have some endpoints on the backend that I want to hit from the frontend, for example to fill 'select' widgets options with data fetched from the backend or to write some data to a database controlled by the backend.

How can I make sure my endpoints are safe and only my React frontend will be able to hit them ?

I read about using JWT, but from what I understand the token will need to be generated on the backend and sent to the user during login. The problem is the login on my frontend doesn't involve anything on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

> The user auth is directly handled by the frontend with the help of Firebase Authentication

I assume that you use [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth) on the frontend and invoke a method such as  [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) or [`signInWithPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithphonenumber) with user's login credentials. Such sign in methods return a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth#usercredential) object which has an **ID Token** for the user.

When you make backend calls, you can include this ID token on those requests as a header. Then on the backend you can use the [Firebase Admin Auth SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin)'s [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) method to verify the received ID token.